# Getting error when starting iis, vs 2017 on windows 10

Tags: iis

Can you help me to fix this error with the iis? I tried more ways but not sure what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Like the error says remove the error extensionless url handler handler mapping from that web.config

Comment: It works on other computers of my colleague, and it dont work only on my pc

Comment: that's probably because the setting is specific to your IIS install. Check the machine.config for your .NET version